# Lzma Audio files

Tags: lzma

Hello I have been trying to extract the following audio file (wav) using the lzma compression

using unxz,xzcat ,lzma ,unlzma,lzcat and other stuff but its either not detected as a valid or returns a 0kb file after decompression.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KImPQsDOqOYY3DoY_ZuAZA4yP2wNbeH8/view?usp=sharing

Do you have any ideas how to go around with that?

Answer (score 1):

Running `binwalk` on your file shows that the LZMA part starts at offset 32:

```
$ binwalk sound.wav.lzma

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
32            0x20            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 700476 bytes
```

So let's try to skip the first 32 bytes and run `unlzma -d` on it:

```
$ dd if=sound.wav.lzma bs=1 skip=32 | unlzma -d > sound.wav
unlzma: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
$ wc -c sound.wav
700476 sound.wav
```

We can see that the LZMA data is corrupt, but we were still able to extract the same size as the one reported by `binwalk`.

The generated `sound.wav` file is a valid wav file 3sec wav file that can be heard without any problem.

So even though your file is odd and maybe corrupted, we were able to extract a valid wav file from it. How did you get that file in the first place?